# How to get notified when AVPlayerViewController exitFullScreenAnimated

Tags: ios, swift

How can I get a callback/notified using NSNotification when AVPlayerViewController exists the full screen, I am able to get notified when it is finished playing using *AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime* but how to achieve *exitFullScreenAnimated* .

Comment: I have faced same problem. Please give any solution.